# Get id of next tr based on class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have one to many table rows containing form inputs that I want to have a totals row under them. I'm adding a dummy table row that I then want to find and use for the totals. I thought I could just do something like `$(this).closest("tr").find(".class").attr("id");"`, but I always get undefined.

For a example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".totals").change(function() {                           
        var tid = $(this).closest("tr").find(".totalsrow").attr("id");
        alert("id is " + tid);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>              

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="100%"> 
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong>                    
            </tr>                                                                
            <tr>
                <td>val</td>
                <td>val</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="1" name="1" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="2" name="2" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="3" name="3" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val</td>
                <td>val</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="4" name="4" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="5" name="5" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="6" name="6" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="totals1" class="totalsrow"></tr>                                
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong></td>
                <td><strong>header</strong>                    
            </tr>                                                                
            <tr>
                <td>val</td>
                <td>val</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="1" name="1" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="2" name="2" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="3" name="3" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val</td>
                <td>val</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="4" name="4" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="5" name="5" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="6" name="6" value="" class="totals" size="5" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="totals2" class="totalsrow"></tr>
        </table>                                 
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on which input I was entering information in, I would expect to either get back `totals1` or `totals2`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.closest() searches the ancestor tree for a matching element here you are looking for a next sibling element.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".totals").change(function() {                           
        var tid = $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".totalsrow").last().next().attr("id");
        alert("id is " + tid);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36UGu/)

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)
- [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 0):

This also works using nextAll().

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".totals").change(function() {                           
        var tid = $(this).closest("tr").nextAll(".totalsrow").attr("id");
        alert("id is " + tid);
    });
});
```